# Faster solution for checking if value is already in another dataframe with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is my code right now:

```py
for i, row in gdf_pot.iterrows():
        if row.ID not in historized.ID.to_list():
            gdf_pot.at[i, "FLAG_NEW"] = 1
        else:
            gdf_pot.at[i, "FLAG_NEW"] = 0
```

It's very slow, because the dataframe is very big.

I saw some solutions with `np.where` but I could'nt make it work.

Maybe you have some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

> The core data structure in GeoPandas is the geopandas.GeoDataFrame, **a subclass of pandas.DataFrame**

```
gdf_pot["FLAG_NEW"] = gdf_pot["ID"].isin(historized["ID"]).astype(int)
```

*NB : `True` behaves as 1 and `False` as 0 in Python. So, when we call `astype(int)`, the boolean Series returned by `isin()` is mapped implicitly to those two numbers.*